# How do I use filtering by getting the first 8 values

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, filter

How can i use filter in windows application, i need to filter cell with number like
002 99 1 1234, now i need to filter this number taking first 8 values from it (002 99 1),

an example of how I thought it :i have numbers (002 99 1 1234),
(002 99 2 1234) and i need to seperate it on:

Create checkboxes: type1 ,type2

and when I check type1 it should open for me all numbers with (002 99 1 ....),
same thing for type2 (002 99 2 ....).

Look at my code, i already use some filters for other cells bu i need this one to.

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Filter for Organizaciona Jedinica
        string filterdata = "";
        if(dtOrgUnit98.Checked)
        {
            if(dtOrgUnit99.Checked)
                {
                    filterdata = "'98' ,";
                }
            else
                {
                    filterdata = "'98'";
                }
        }
        if (dtOrgUnit99.Checked)
        {
            if (dtOrgUnit98.Checked)
                {
                    filterdata = "'99' ,";
                }
                else
                {
                    filterdata = "'99'";
                }
        }

        //Filter for Status
        string filterstatus = "";
        if (dtOtpis.Checked)
        {
            if (dtUskladisteno.Checked)
            {
                filterstatus = "'74' ,";
            }
            else
            {
                filterstatus = "'74'";
            }
        }
        if (dtUskladisteno.Checked)
        {
            if (dtOtpis.Checked)
            {
                filterstatus = "'5' ,";
            }
            else
            {
                filterstatus = "'5'";
            }
        }

        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                db.Open();
            string query = "select barcode, idstatus, description, dateofstatus, idorgunit" +
                            " from archivebook" +
                           $" where dateofstatus between '{ dtDateFrom.Value}' and '{ dtDateTo.Value}'  and idstatus in (" + filterstatus + ") and idorgunit in (" + filterdata + ")";
```

Comment: Do you get the number to filter like this: (002 99 1 1234) or like that: (002 99 1 1234), (002 99 2 1234) or 002 99 1 1234? Is this user input? Maybe you can add the aspx code too.

Comment: I have database, and values in it, but i need this cell to ge filtered, and i have 2000+ values in that cell and numbers in this two format :
002 99 1  (random four numbers)
002 99 2  (random four numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter based on user input I would do it like that:

```
string sDataToFilter = "002 99 1 1234"; //Replace the string with the value you get from your code
filterdata = sDataToFilter.Substring(0, 8);
filterdata = "'" + filterdata + "'"; // for use in SQL query
```

If you only need to number after 002 99 1 then I would do this:

```
string sDataToFilter = "002 99 1 1234";
filterdata = sDataToFilter.Substring(0, 8);  // will be 002 99 1
sRestNumbers = sDataToFilter.Replace(filterdata, ""); //will be 1234
```

Hope this helps or at least guides you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Just by using this line
filterData= Data.Substring(0, 8);

Comment: Look, i have 5 types of this code and all of these have ID, 
002 99 1 (some four numbers)
002 99 2 (some four numbers)
002 99 3 (some four numbers)
002 99 4 (some four numbers)
002 99 5 (some four numbers)
ID IS ,1,2,3,4,5, AND FOR EXAMPLE i have 2000 codes, what i need is filter exp when i click example checkbox called TYPE 3 which is ID 3 or 002 99 3 (random four numbers) i should have result of example 200 codes with that ID. 
And i need that for all of these codes.